# exec master..xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me resolve the syntax in the following script? Here @Name and @DBname are declared above.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo 'alter login QUOTENAME(select @Name) with default_database =  QUOTENAME(select @DBname) >> C:\test\test_script.txt''
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Declare @Name varchar(30) = 'Bob'
Declare @DBname sysname = 'TestDb'
Declare @Cmd varchar(4000)
set @Cmd = 'echo ' + 'alter login ' + QUOTENAME(@Name) + ' with default_database = ' + QUOTENAME(@DBname) + ' >> C:\test\test_script.txt'
print @Cmd
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed the other answer someone put while I was typing, that answer should work too but the output >> X:\folder\file.ext should be quoted with double quotes to ensure it still operates when there are spaces in the path or filename.

I get what you're trying to do.
This should accomplish the result you appear to want.

```
declare @name varchar(128) = 'sa',@DBname varchar(128) = 'model'
declare @cmd_text varchar(8000) = 'echo alter login ' + quotename(@Name) + ' with default_database = ' + quotename(@DBname) + ' >> "D:\test_script.sql"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd_text
```

put in your own path for the file, you want a script file with executable scripts to change users default databases. Double checked to make sure it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Other folks have helped to resolve your issue, but xp_cmdshell is not the right approach in your case.

You should use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) - [`Set-DbaLogin`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Set-DbaLogin) to set the default database for the login.

e.g. `Set-DbaLogin -SqlInstance sql1 -Login login1 -DefaultDatabase master`

To export as script, you can use [`Export-DbaScript`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Export-DbaScript).